# How much of Pascal's triangle does this evaluate?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

If I have this constant `pascal` defined as

```
pascal :: [[Int]]
pascal = iterate newrow [1]
  where newrow = (zipWith (+) <*> tail) . ([0]++) . (++[0])
```

And I evaluate `pascal !! 50 !! 50` in GHCI, how much of the triangle does this evaulate? Does that laziness mean only the necessary values (plus a bunch of thunks) get calculated?

Comment: yes - this will create you all the thunks up to the `!! 50 !! 50` and evaluate the ones needet to calculate this entry.

Comment: In GHCi, try `:sprint pascal` after evaluating a particular location, like `pascal !! 50 !! 50`, and you can see what has been evaluated and what hasn't been.

Comment: @kosmikus +1 - you should make this an answer! - If you include the output (or a screenshot) it will be even more impressive - I am thinking about printing this out and hanging it on my board right now ("hey what is this?" - <<haskell>> - "....oh") :D

Comment: Nice. `newrow = zipWith (+) . (0:) <*> (++[0])`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, only the elements that are required to compute the element in question are evaluated.

GHCi offers the `:sprint` and `:print` debugging commands that can give you some information about what parts of a value have already been evaluated.

On this example:

```
GHCi> :sprint pascal
pascal = _
```

(That's because nothing has been evaluated at this point, and thunks are shown as `_`.)

```
GHCi> pascal !! 5 !! 5
1
```

(I'm not using `50` because then this example would become too long.)

```
GHCi> :sprint pascal
pascal = [1] : [_,1] : [_,_,1] : [_,_,_,1] : [_,_,_,_,1] :
         (_ : _ : _ : _ : _ : 1 : _) : _
```

Now you get a pretty clear idea what parts have been looked at.

Let's try one more:

```
GHCi> pascal !! 5 !! 4
5
GHCi> :sprint pascal
pascal = [1] : [1,1] : [_,2,1] : [_,_,3,1] : [_,_,_,4,1] :
         (_ : _ : _ : _ : 5 : 1 : _) : _
```

And another one:

```
GHCi> pascal !! 10 !! 5
252
GHCi> :sprint pascal
pascal = [1] : [1,1] : [1,2,1] : [1,3,3,1] : [1,4,6,4,1] :
         (1 : 5 : 10 : 10 :   5 :   1 : _) :
         (_ : 6 : 15 : 20 :  15 :   6 : _) :
         (_ : _ : 21 : 35 :  35 :  21 : _) : 
         (_ : _ : _  : 56 :  70 :  56 : _) :
         (_ : _ : _  : _  : 126 : 126 : _) : 
         (_ : _ : _  : _  : _   : 252 : _) : _
```